# Activate Modern Audience targeting on Site pages with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, audience-targeting, communication-site

I'm trying to find a way to enable modern audience targeting on the Site Pages library of a Communication site with PowerShell.

Activating the hidden feature does not have any effect. Is this possible?

Comment: By modern audience target do you mean enabling **Enable audience targeting** settings  which is available under Library Settings -> Audience Targeting Settings? and by enabling this settings "Audience" column will be added to library where you can define list of groups for target audience?

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela Yes exactly this

Comment: @RobertLindgren Check if this helps to convert PowerShell for SP online: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/enable-audience-targeting-for-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/

Comment: @GaneshSanap that is for the classic audience targeting I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it can be done via PowerShell, however it can be achieved via the [EnableModernAudienceTargeting](https://pnp.github.io/pnpframework/api/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListExtensions.html#Microsoft_SharePoint_Client_ListExtensions_EnableModernAudienceTargeting_List_) method in the PnP Framework (heavily reliant on CSOM). You can find the underlying code for this in [ListExtensions.cs](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/a433cd87d7c5c3deff5cb88e42259ab34eb362f4/src/lib/PnP.Framework/Extensions/ListExtensions.cs#L2305)

```
public static void EnableModernAudienceTargeting(this List list)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly like what I'm after. Then I just need to convert that csom code to powershell  and try it out. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Cool, yes you could do that. Alternatively, you could put a PR in to PnP.PowerShell for the Set-PnPList cmdlet. I couldn't find this functionality there when I looked.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, trying to convert that code to PS :( Might be something in my conversion that i acting up, but even if all goes through the values are not stored properly in the targeting column (it gets emptied on refresh)

Comment: might be worth checking the method works in a simple C# application first. There's an odd "to do" in the method, I don't know what it's referring to https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/a433cd87d7c5c3deff5cb88e42259ab34eb362f4/src/lib/PnP.Framework/Extensions/ListExtensions.cs#L2307